# What are sha1sum "exit codes"?

Tags: bash, exit-code, sha1sum

1) Is there any documentation/URL about sha1sum  "exit codes"? I am just want to be sure, that "exit code 1" always means that there is a "FAILED result".

```
$ sha1sum dummy* > SHA1SUM
$ sha1sum -c SHA1SUM 
dummy1: OK
dummy2: OK
dummy3: OK
$ echo $?
0
$ ls > dummy1
$ sha1sum -c SHA1SUM 
dummy1: FAILED
dummy2: OK
dummy3: OK
sha1sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
$ echo $?
1
$ ls > dummy2
$ sha1sum -c SHA1SUM 
dummy1: FAILED
dummy2: FAILED
dummy3: OK
sha1sum: WARNING: 2 computed checksums did NOT match
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: OK, I have deleted question number 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit code `1` can mean other errors, for instance permission failure or file not found (which will be counted as a `FAILED` result though).

```shell
touch foo
sha1sum foo > foo.sha1
mv foo bar
sha1sum foo.sha1 # will fail with $? == 1
```